# Using NSFetchedResultsController and UISearchDisplayController crashes app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have successfully implemented `NSFetchedResultsController` and `UISearchDisplayController` together on my app, the app will crash ONLY after using the `UISearchDisplayController` (after pressing on its Cancel button), the crash happens exactly while scrolling down the table view, the console shows this message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
reason: 'no object at index 5 in section at index 0'
```

giving that scrolling down the table view before using the `UISearchDisplayController` will not crash the app.

what is the problem reason in this case ?

Comment: problem solved by resetting the old fetched results controller and creating a new one.

Comment: I was having the exact same setup and same problem as yours .... yeah i set the fetchedResultsController to nil when cancel button is pressed. And it works now. Thank you. But do you know why it works after setting the fetchedResultsController to nil?

Comment: @nick32m no i don't have an idea about that

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with one of my apps, when the Apple released the new iOS 4.0. Search:

```
fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
```

And set the value of the parameter cacheName to nil. It worked for me, hope it will for you. It is not necessary to create new fetch result controller each time.